# django modelform submission

Tags: django, modelform

I am working on a django project, The model CaseRegister i am trying to submit values using model form. My model class belo

```
             - model.py

            from django.db import models

            from core.models import ProviderMaster,FacilityMaster,ProviderMaster,CaseMaster,CasestatusMaster  
            from patient.models import PatientMaster   
            from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
            from django.forms import ModelForm  
            from account.models import Profile

            def update_id(func):
               def decorated_function(*args):        
                    data_object = args[0]            
                    sequence_name = 'seq_%s' % data_object._meta.db_table        
                    from django.db import connection
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("SELECT nextval(%s)", [sequence_name])
                    row = cursor.fetchone()        
                    data_object.caseid = row[0]   
                    return func(*args)    
                return decorated_function

            class CaseRegister(models.Model):
                caseid = models.DecimalField(primary_key=True, max_digits=8, decimal_places=0)
                patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='patientid') 
                case_startdate = models.DateField()
                case_enddate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
                providerid = models.ForeignKey(ProviderMaster, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='providerid', blank=True, null=True)
                facilityid = models.ForeignKey(FacilityMaster, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='facilityid', blank=True, null=True)
                casetypeid = models.ForeignKey(CaseMaster, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='casetypeid', blank=True, null=True)
                casestatus = models.ForeignKey(CasestatusMaster, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='casestatus', blank=True, null=True)    
                approved_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
                last_modifieduser = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='last_modifieduser')
                class Meta:
                    managed = False
                    db_table = 'case_register'
                def __str__(self):
                    return self.caseid
                @update_id
                def save(self):
                    # Now actually save the object.
                    super(CaseRegister, self).save()
```

The form is created as below and mapped query set for all FK fields

```
     - The form.py

        from django import forms
        from .models import CaseRegister
        from  patient.models import PatientMaster
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        from account.models import Profile,ProfileFaciltiyMembership
        from  core.models import FacilityMaster,CasestatusMaster,ProviderMaster,ProviderCategory,RoleMaster
        from django.db.models import Q
        import datetime

        class CaseRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = CaseRegister
                fields = ('caseid', 'patient', 'case_startdate',"case_enddate","facilityid","providerid","casetypeid","casestatus","last_modifieduser" )
            def __init__(self, p,profile,request, *args, **kwargs):
                super(CaseRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                print("request.method   "+request.method)
                if (request.method=='GET'):
                    print("request.method   "+request.method)
                    self.fields['patient'].empty_label = None
                    self.fields['patient'].label="Patient"      
                    self.fields['patient'].queryset = PatientMaster.objects.filter(patientid=p.patientid)               
                    self.fields['patient'].widget.attrs = {'maxlength': 10}
                    self.fields['patient'].widget.attrs = {'disabled': True}

                self.fields['case_startdate'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'vDateField'}
                self.fields['case_startdate'].label="Date"
                self.fields['case_startdate'].initial=datetime.datetime.now().date()

                #self.fields['last_modifieduser'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=profile.user)
                self.fields['last_modifieduser'].queryset = Profile.objects.all()
                self.fields['last_modifieduser'].empty_label = None
                #self.fields['last_modifieduser'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()      
                self.fields['caseid'].required = False      
                self.fields['caseid'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
                self.fields['case_enddate'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
                fid =  request.session["currfacility"]      
                self.fields['facilityid'].empty_label = None
                self.fields['facilityid'].queryset = FacilityMaster.objects.filter(facilityid=fid)
                self.fields['facilityid'].widget.attrs = {'disabled': True}
                self.fields['casestatus'].empty_label = None
                self.fields['casestatus'].queryset=CasestatusMaster.objects.filter(casestatusid=1)
                facility=FacilityMaster.objects.get(pk=fid)
                profiles=Profile.objects.filter(facilities=facility)
                providercat = ProviderCategory.objects.get(pk=2)
                self.fields['providerid'].empty_label = None    
                self.fields['providerid'].label="Physician" 
                self.fields['casetypeid'].label="Type"
                self.fields['casetypeid'].empty_label = None    
                self.fields['casestatus'].label="Status"    
                criterion1 = Q(profile__in=profiles)
                criterion2 = Q(pcategoryid=providercat)
                rid = request.session["currrole"]
                print(rid)
                if rid == str(2) :
                    print("if")         
                    profile = request.user.profile
                    pfid = profile.provider.providerid
                    print(pfid)
                    criterion3 = Q(providerid=pfid)
                    self.fields['providerid'].queryset =  ProviderMaster.objects.filter(criterion3 & criterion2)
                else:
                    print("else")
                    self.fields['providerid'].queryset =  ProviderMaster.objects.filter(criterion1 & criterion2)
```

The below is the  view and inthe GET method i am assigning a patient id and in 
POST request i am not doing anything to the modelform.
 - view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import CaseRegisterForm
from .models import CaseRegister
from patient.models import PatientMaster
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DetailView, UpdateView


def caseregister(request):
    pid =1413963        
    if request.method == "POST":                
        form = CaseRegisterForm(None,request.user.profile,request,request.POST)                                
        #form = CaseRegisterForm(request.POST)                                
        print(form.is_valid())
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():                             

            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)            
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('{% url "createcase" %}')
    else:
        pid =1413963
        p = PatientMaster.objects.get(pk=pid)
        form = CaseRegisterForm(p,request.user.profile,request)        
        return render(request, "case_register.html", {'form': form})
```

While submitting the form i am getting the error - patient -This field is required message.
I tried to map query set patient  in post method  same as like get. I am getting the same error.